# creating hex byte array in java

Tags: java, hex, arrays, checksum

Here is the problem, I need to do it in Java:
I need to create a byte array with hex values, to send via socket to a device. message format is something like this

> STX cmd1 Arg1 , cmd2  ETX Checksum  // Any number of commands and arguments

Example :
 STX  A 1 ETX 148  // 1 and 148 are in decimal STX is 0x02 and ETX is 0x03 , not text STX and ETX.

The byte array which is to be generated for the above example is this :

> ```
>     STX         A            1         ETX         148
> ```

```
    {(byte)0x2,(byte)0x41,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x3, (byte)0x94}
```

Can you please help me. How do I do convert these numbers/characters and assign to byte array?

Comment: What? `byte[] buffer = {(byte)0x2,(byte)0x41,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x3, (byte)0x94};`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks, how to convert Ato 0x41 , 148 to 0x94 and assign to byte array is the question. the one given is an example. STX and ETX static, but A and 1 will vary.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis These are commands to the device, examples are 1)  A ,1 , 2) P,10 3) ?K etc . I have to append checksum then to that(0-256). All these I have to send in the format explained in question.

Comment: What is your input in Java? Are these strings, chars, bytes, ints? We're converting from one thing to another. We need to know their types.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis only ints and chars, double i have to parse and send as individual digits, including dot(.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, you're already heading in the right direction.

A few things to know, an unsigned byte goes from 0 to 255 (0x00 to 0xFF).  In Java, there are only signed data types and a byte goes from -128 to +127.

```
System.out.println(Byte.MIN_VALUE); // -128
System.out.println(Byte.MAX_VALUE); // +127
```

If fields 3 & 5 are `int`s casting them to `byte`s is fine, but know that anything that is over +127 when casted to a byte will overflow into the negative range.

```
System.out.println((byte)0x94); // -108
System.out.println((byte)148);  // -108
```

If you're wanting the actual positive value of the byte you can `AND` each byte against 0xFF.

```
System.out.println(((byte)-108) & 0xFF); // +148
System.out.println(((byte)-1) & 0xFF);   // +255
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. With your answer I am close to the solution, Just one problem. May be if I get an answer to this query, I might achieve the target. Shouldnt System.out.println((byte)0x31 ) and System.out.println((byte)1) be printing the same answer 49 ? I am getting 49 for first and 1 for second. This is where I am stuck now. If my 3rd field value is 1, I am expecting 49 (0x31), but I am getting 1 (0x1 )

Comment: @Shar1e80 , I got the problem. Confusion between 1 and '1' . Your explanation really helped me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use what Sotirios Delimanolis proposed in the comments and put your char variables in there?

```
char a = 'A';
char b = '1';
byte[] buffer = {(byte)0x2, (byte)a, (byte)b, (byte)0x3, (byte)0x94};
```

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: thankyou, The one you have quoted will work, but the problem is, b is an integer , it can be two or three digits also. If I assign char b = 1 without quotes(' ') , it is coming as 0x1, not 0x31.  In the question, 148 should populated as 0x94 , dynamically - it is not hard coded.